# Windows 7 - nVidia graphics card and Windows Update problems

Tags: windows-7, nvidia-graphics-card

Ok let me explain my problem and what I did step by step.

1) Playing a Java game(Not full screen) in high fps using nvidia graphics card.

2) Suddenly, my computer graphics seen like "crash". The icons in my desktop and taskbar disappear! But I am still able to play that Java game in high fps.

3) After a few second, everything came back

4) I quit the game for a while, and I launched it again. The game is soooo lag! Only 20-30 
fps

5) I went to the task bar and see the "small icon(with sound volume, battery info, etc)" 
in right side. The nVidia icon didn't "light"! That means nVidia is not using.

6) I went to nVidia Control Panel, wait and wait, a dialog pop up, "nVidia Control Panel is not responding" "Windows is checking for solution....."

7) Now I went to nVidia GeForce. It said a new update is avaliable, which is the update I installed about a week ago. I installed it again. It required a restart, so I restart my computer.

8) While the computer is shutting down, it's installing update.

9) The computer started again, at the welcome screen, it said something like Failed to configuration update... reverting blah blah . The computer restarted again, "please wait blah blah don't power off your computer". After that, it asked my to type my password.

10) Usually nVidia GeForce will pop up and completing my installation but this time it doesn't. I launched it again, "An update is avaliable". :( I clicked Express Installation as usual like before.

11) Installation failed!
[image: :(]

12) I tried and tried again still same :(

13) I am not able to install windows update as well
[image: :'(]

14) Error log
[image: :(((]

Can anyone help me please! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure on how to do this with windows 7 because I use windows 8 but you need to go to the Device Manager selection probably under control panel, once you get there you should see display adapters, click that and right click on your graphics card, you should then be able to update the graphics card driver, then use the internet to update it, I don't know if this helps but give it a go.!

[image: !Driver Update]

Comment: Finally a reply! My nVidia graphics card is not there.

Comment: Well that means that the drivers are not there and you are in fact not using your graphics cards at all thats why it lags, i suggest using this website to manually install your driver and see if that helps. i don't know much about Nvidia because i use AMD so if this doesn't work i don't know what else to do sorry.  http://www.nvidia.co.uk/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-uk